# Scanner int and String

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I have a txt file that need to be read into the program.
The format of the content in the file is like this:

```
1, Q, 0
1, S, 4
1, E, 3
1, W, 2
1, N, 5
2, Q, 0
2, N, 5
3, Q, 0
```

The code below does not work:

```
sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("dirFile.txt"));
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                sc.useDelimiter(", ");
                int loc = sc.nextInt();
                sc.skip(sc.delimiter());
                String description = sc.next();
                sc.skip(sc.delimiter());
                int locID = sc.nextInt();                   // Line 70
                sc.nextLine();                              // Line 71
                locations.get(loc).addExits(description, locID);
            }
```

But if I change line 70 and line 71 into the code below, it works:

```
        String temp = sc.nextLine();
        int locID = Integer.parseInt(temp);
```

I guess The problem of the first code is something wrong with scanner reading the integer. If I let scanner read it as String and then parse it into int, it will be fine. But I'm not sure why the first code not work. It does not make sense to me. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the first code?

Comment: `Scanner` returns tokens separated by the delimiter, so you don't need to skip the delimiter. However, you shouldn't use `Scanner` for this *(not the right tool for this job, and it's slow)*. Use a `BufferedReader` to read the lines, and `split(", ")` each line.

Answer (score 0):

Your text consist of `,` and new line delimiter `\n`. You must combine them.

Moreover, that setting should be set outside the while loop:

```
sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("dirFile.txt"));
sc.useDelimiter(", |\\n");
while() {
  ///
}
```